# append script to existing page

Tags: php, html, curl, append

good day everyone!

i am trying to append a script to a remote page (not mine and it is a form page) that would hide some of its content (some  in particular) before showing it. i am using curl but the only thing i could do is retrieve its html code.

is there anyway of doing what i wanted to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the user asks your server for content, and your server needs to fetch that content on another server and process it before sending it back to the user.

Query the other script using CURL, then run your script on that HTML to remove the pieces that you don't want to keep (I hope for your sake that they are reasonably easy to find and eliminate), and finally output the resulting HTML to the user.

Answer (score 0):

To remove some part of the html, you could preg_replace() it using regular expressions.

Googling for an *online regexp* might be of some help, if you have no experience with regular expressions.

Comment: it will if you load the page with CURL first